# Providing static variable to parent class

Tags: c#, database

I want to make class with tools for managing DB tables. But I need to somehow send back table name to the tools class from data class. I managed to make this work in non-static environment, but I need to make this work also in static functions.

I did some Googling, but I found nothing helpful.

Example usage:

Caller

```
User.Delete(1);
```

Tools class

```
public class DBTools
{
    public static string table_name = "NULL"; 

    public static void Delete(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(table_name);
    }
    ...
}
```

Data class

```
public class User : DBTools
{
    public new static string table_name = "users";
    ...
}
```

Comment: This sounds as a good arguments for using (virtual) instance(not static) method and properties vs static methods and properties. it would be very easy to implement what you want if you just use a (virtual) property string and just call `new User().Delete(1);`
Every time you use static members, you are creating an obstacle for using inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to create a `Delete()` method in any class derived from `DBTools`, and have it simply call the base class's `Delete()` method *(which could still do all the heavy lifting)* and pass it the correct table name.

```
public class DBTools
{
    public string table_name = "NULL";

    public void Delete(string table_name, int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(table_name);

        // whatever work is required for the given table name
    }
}

public class User : DBTools
{
    public string table_name = "users";

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Delete(table_name, id);
    }
}
```